# Pan card and foreign exchanges in india

Tags: india, money

As I am 15 years I wanted to go abroad but there is one problem. I need the pan card to go abroad so that I can collect money. The question is that can I get pan card in this age and can we carry foreign currency to abroad?

Comment: By the way, since you have been asking a couple of questions now and got answers, you can "accept" the best answer to a question as the right one with the checkmark below the vote buttons! This is reward the person answered and also help future people having the same question.

Answer (score 4):

There is [no age limit](http://www.indg.in/e-governance/vle-corner/apply-online-for-pan-card) for a PAN card. I would make sure however that you can use the PAN card in all your target countries.

Otherwise you can carry the [equivalent of 2'000 USD](http://www.immihelp.com/newcomer/foreign-exchange-india.html) in foreign currency along with you. Also, you can take 5'000 RS with you, except for Nepal and Buthan.

If you carry a lot of cash please be careful. There are recently more and more reported thefts in airplanes reported. Items are often taken out of the overhead luggage compartment when people are sleeping.